# Controller [Authorize] thinks I'm unauthorized after successful login

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, blazor, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

I have been trying to improve security of the api's in the application by adding a `[Authorize]` attribute. However even after a successful login, the controller still seems to think I am unauthorized producing the error below. I am using Identity Server (ASP.NET Hosted Blazor web assembly project template)

### Error

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
  Unhandled exception rendering component: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 

(Unauthorized).
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.<GetFromJsonAsyncCore>d__9`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[WebApp.Shared.Ticket, WebApp.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at WebApp.Client.Pages.Index.OnInitializedAsync() in C:\Users\Shahb\source\repos\WebApp\WebApp\Client\Pages\Index.razor:line 114
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

*Line 114 referenced in the error is a GET API request to controller marked [Authorized]*

### Controller

```
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TicketsController : ControllerBase
{

//...
}
```

### Startup.cs

```
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
                options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
                options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
            });

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

       services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize);

        services.AddSwaggerGen();
    
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you configuring Identity Server services?

Comment: @ArturoMartinez Thanks for the reply. This would be in the Startup.cs file? I will add this to the post

Comment: From my experience, putting IdentityServer with your client/API is a bad idea, as it makes it much harder to troubleshoot, debug and reason about.

Comment: Can you show the Blazor code where you configure the HttpClient please. Also include where you access said client and use it. It should be a factory pattern.